# This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes

Tags: android, google-play-console, multiple-apk, android-multiple-apk

[][1]

{
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.test"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 30
versionCode 64
if (taggedRelease == null) {
versionName "1.4.1-SNAPSHOT"
} else {
versionName = taggedRelease
}
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
multiDexEnabled true
}
signingConfigs {
release
}
flavorDimensions "abi"

```
productFlavors {
    x64 {
        dimension "abi"
        versionCode 30000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        versionNameSuffix "-x86_64"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86_64","armeabi","arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    arm {
        dimension "abi"
        versionCode 10000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        versionNameSuffix "-arm"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","armeabi","arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    arm64 {
        dimension "abi"
        versionCode 20000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        versionNameSuffix "-arm64"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a","armeabi","arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
}
```

}
any one can you please help me to resolve this error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwYbM.png

Comment: Why do you have different version codes for the same version with different ABIs?  THat's not how you're supposed to do things.  1 version code across all the abis, and the play store will send it the appropriate abi for the device.

Comment: Gabe, you are incorrect. See https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks : "Each APK must have a different version code". Although it's true that uploading one App Bundle instead of three APKs would alleviate all your problems.

Comment: Cooper, it would help if you uploaded a screenshot showing the artifacts present in the release. Your versionCode scheme looks reasonable but I'd rather see what's shown in the Play Console (below the error messages).